# Copying an ELF section between object files with binutils

Tags: linker, elf, binutils

Due to a bug in `ld` I need to copy an ELF section from one object file to another. I can dump the desired section to a file but the problem is that `objcopy`'s `--add-section` option expects a binary file and the section type information is therefore lost. As far as I can tell I cannot set the type of a section using binutils but I'm hoping I'm wrong :)

I can edit the binary manually to set the section type and that
solves the underlying problem, but I'm curious as to whether there's a solution based on standard tools.

For the curious the underlying problem is that when GNU `ld` links an
ARM object file without the `.ARM.attributes` section (such as a file
with just a binary blob living in its own section) it picks some
default that causes it to generate invalid veneers to RAM-functions
even when the files containing the calls have good `.ARM.attributes`
sections. The only solution (pending
https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=11897) that I can come up with is to add a `.ARM.attributes` section to the binary-blob object file. However, that only works if the `.ARM.attributes` section has the type `ARM_ATTRIBUTES`.